# Tor Downloads/ Anonymity

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, security, onion-routing, deanonymization

I had a question regarding Downloading files Using the Tor software . Lets say you are a journalist and you were on some website on TOR (like a .onion) and you needed to download standard MP4/ PNG/ JPG files (Media) from that random website. Would it be safe to then open those types of files on a computer outside of the tor software ? (Like using windows media player or something).

I have read online that the government/ other people can bug files and these types of media that so when you open them, they can track you. Is this true? And if you did this would your identity / location be compromised?

If this is true and it’s not safe, what would happen if you still downloaded the files from tor onto like a usb stick, and then disposed of the computer, moved locations, and plugged that usb into another computer that’s never connected to the internet and accessed the media files . Would you then be safe even if the files were bugged?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a brilliant question! Yes, you **must** use a separate *environment* for opening content, and a separate physical machine is a good choice, but - there's also a QubesOS that utilizes virtualization to achieve the same capabilities using software. Check it here (https://www.qubes-os.org/)[https://www.qubes-os.org/], and use a **Disposable VM instance** instead of a separate hardware